# Typescript error "children does not exists on type IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes<unknown>'.* " on react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

Error:

*Type '{ children: string; severity: string; sx: { width: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes'.
Property 'children' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & RefAttributes'.*

Alert component

```
const Alert = React.forwardRef(function Alert(props, ref) {
  const ref_var = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} ref={ref_var} variant="filled" {...props} />;
});
```

Using Alert component

```
 <Alert severity="success" sx={{ width: "100%" }}>
         Success
        </Alert>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The custom Alert component implementation is correct, but you have to mention the `React.forwardRef`'s props `React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, AlertProps>` to solve the TypeScript compilation issues.

Also, the local `ref` variable `ref_var` is not required.

```
    const AlertFixed = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, AlertProps>(
  (props, ref) => (
    <MuiAlert elevation={6} ref={ref} variant="filled" {...props} />
  )
);
```

and call the `Alert` component,

```
<AlertFixed severity="error" sx={{ width: "50%" }}>
  Failed
</AlertFixed>
```

Here is the working [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-q-71459618-mui-alert-l6e03v?file=/demo.tsx:756-842).